# something similar as jira for rpi

Tags: pi-2, software-installation, software-recommendation

I have rpi model b 2. I wan't to install some kind of management solution tool (like jira). Problem is I don't know what should I choose, because rpi have too small resources. For an example, jira require 2gb ram (and not work with open jre).

If anybody install such applications on rpi, please respond.

Answer (score 1):

I use and love phabricator, php on nginx with MySQL, haven’t tried on rpi but a lot lighter weight than jira.

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/installation_guide/